# WMI Remote Monitoring getting The RPC Server is unavailable. Windows Server 2019

Tags: wmi, windows-server-2019

I'm having trouble connecting to a remote machine via WMI. Getting the error message

`The RPC Server is unavailable`

1. I've ensured that the `Remote Procedure Call` service is turned on.
2. I've opened all necessary ports in the firewall.
3. I've turned off the firewall altogether to eliminate any possibility it's the firewall for testing. Both on Server & Client
4. I've ran the following script via powershell remotely and get the error message.
5. If I run the same powershell script through another server on the same network it works! I get my drive info listed. But it won't work across the internet from my office?!? What am I doing wrong?

`Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\cimv2" -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -ComputerName 192.168.1.1 -Credential MyDomain\Administrator` I did replace the IP to my public IP on this command.

I can ping the IP and **do** get replies.

Comment: You absolutely do not ever want to do this over the internet. Ever. Ever, ever, ever.Use a VPN to remotely manage your servers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say you've changed the IP address to the public IP address, do you mean that you're trying to do this over the internet? If so, you'll need to configure the router that the server is ultimately connected to to forward TCP 135 to your server's internal IP address.

Please note that opening up ports like this is **absolutely not recommended**. Assuming you're doing this over the internet, you'd be better off creating a VPN between your client and server.

Comment: Just re-read your post and noticed the line where you mention that you are trying to do this over the internet. My post above is the correct answer, but as stated, you absolutely should not do this.

Comment: i'll look into VPN.